# IE 10 Compat View - IE5 Quriks filter not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, background-image, internet-explorer-10

We have a legacy system that uses below as background.

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=1, enabled='true', startColorstr=#ff00008B, endColorstr=#A000008B);`

now since IE10 no longer supports DX Gradients, i have tried to use below instead yet the IE browser does not render the background correctly

`background: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #05008A 0%, #6982B5 100%);`

Is there another way to make the gradient work for compatibilty view that uses IE5 Quirks?

Thanks

Comment: Still supporting IE5 ?

Comment: not really, the ie 10 browser just load the screen using ie10 compatibilty view browser mode and IE5 Quirks document mode by default